# Best practice for Native calls from C#

Tags: c#, performance

I was wondering what are the best practice/design for calling external dependencies from my C# application? My application is distriuted as DLL that is used in other application.

I have a class named OCRObject that i don't know if I should make it static or not.

This is my code that calls the external DLL:

```
/// <summary>
/// A static instance of OCRObject that handles the OCR part of the application. This class
/// calls a native libary and the required files must therfore be present in /Tesseract folder.
/// </summary>
internal class OCRObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calls the Native C++ libary and returns an UTF-8 string of the image text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imagePath">   The full image path.</param>
    /// <param name="tessConfPath">The tesseract configuration path.</param>
    /// <param name="tessLanguage">The tesseract language.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    public string GetOCRText(string imagePath, string tessConfPath, string tessLanguage)
    {
        try
        {
            if (StaticObjectHolder.EnableAdvancedLogging)
            {
                Logger.Log(string.Format("Doing OCR on folder {0}.", imagePath));
            }
            return this.StringFromNativeUtf8(OCRObject.GetUTF8Text(tessConfPath, tessLanguage, imagePath));
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException ave)
        {
            Logger.Log(ave.ToString(), LogInformationType.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex.ToString(), LogInformationType.Error);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The DLL Import declaration. The main entry point is GetUTF8Text which is the method in
    /// the native libary. This method extracts text from the image and returns and UTF-8 representation of the string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">   The path of the configuration files.</param>
    /// <param name="lang">   The language to parse. For example DAN, ENG etc.</param>
    /// <param name="imgPath">The full path of the image to extract image from.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    [DllImport(@"\Tesseract\TesseractX64.dll", EntryPoint = "GetUTF8Text", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetUTF8Text(string path, string lang, string imgPath);

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the returned IntPtr from the native call to a UTF-8 based string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nativeUtf8">The native UTF8.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    private string StringFromNativeUtf8(IntPtr nativeUtf8)
    {
        try
        {
            int len = 0;
            if (nativeUtf8 == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            while (Marshal.ReadByte(nativeUtf8, len) != 0)
            {
                ++len;
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            Marshal.Copy(nativeUtf8, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            nativeUtf8 = IntPtr.Zero; /*set to zero.*/
            return text;
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

I aiming for maximum performance so i was wondering if this code can be optimized by either making this class static or chaning any of the code?

Here is the C++ Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "OCRWrapper.h"
#include "allheaders.h"
#include "baseapi.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream";
#include "vector";
#include "algorithm"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sstream"

OCRWrapper::OCRWrapper()
{
}

//OCRWrapper::~OCRWrapper()
//{
//}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the image path to read text from.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="imgPath">The img path.</param>
/// <summary>
/// Get the text from the image in UTF-8. Remeber to Convert it to UTF-8 again on the callee side.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
char* OCRWrapper::GetUTF8Text(char* path, char* lang, char* imgPath)
{
    char* imageText = NULL;
    try
    {
        tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

        if (api->Init(path, lang)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract. Incorrect datapath or incorrect lanauge\n"); /*This should throw an error to the caller*/
            exit(1);
        }

        /*Open a reference to the imagepath*/
        Pix *image = pixRead(imgPath);

        /*Read the image object;*/
        api->SetImage(image);

        // Get OCR result
        imageText = api->GetUTF8Text();

        /*writeToFile(outText);*/
        /*printf("OCR output:\n%s", imageText);*/

        /*Destroy the text*/
        api->End();

        pixDestroy(&image);
        /*std::string x = std::string(imageText);*/
        return imageText;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::string errorStr("An error occured during OCR. ImgPath => " + std::string(imgPath));
        return &errorStr[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OPtimal performance? Use C++/CLR for interface classes. The difference is small but may be relevant. It is a lot larger if you can avoid string generation - with C# interop strings MUST be marshalled, with C++/CLR you may reuse cached strings. Depends on the lower level API you have downstream.

In terms of OCR, though, I seriously think you bark the wrong tree. OCR is a processor intensive operation, so all you optimize on the calls - few and far between compared to the processing - is just not relevant. The times I am going to optimize this stuff is for example with exchange data streams which may be called hundreds of thousands of times per second - with minimal data forwarding it to processing in C#. But for OCR I have serious problems seeing this as relevant. Especially if and as you do not handle the images to start with - and that is the only way it would make sense to consider optimizations.

How long does a call to GetOCRText take? If it is significantly more than 1/1000th of a second - then seriously you DO try to optimize the wrong element. Call overhead is SMALL (much much much smaller than that).

Comment: It takes around 6 seconds for 12 images (Mult-Thread). For a  single thread it takes around 22 seconds for 12 images. So This is a huge difference. The OCR code is pretty simple (I have updated my question have look please). I don't I can do much more???

Comment: if it takes 6 seconds for 12 images - that is 12 calls to the method. The overhead is likely less than 12 microseconds. There is likely a lot you can do - possibly - but nothing of that has to do with the native call, it all would have to be done on the native side (i.e. making the OCR code faster). And your C++ code is not "simple". It is merely a wrapper around the REAL ocr code - your code has not a single line that does OCR. It takes a long time to process an image, so no, that is not simple. I would likely do the C++ into C++/CLR and make a class directly usable from C# - but for style.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How do I do c++ into C++/CLR and make a class directly usable from C#?

Comment: You start reading the documentation. Seriously, this is too broad for here.